# How many on-going Batman comics are there, and how are they interlinked?

Tags: comics, dc, batman

I'm dipping my toes into the world of on-going Marvel and DC Comics for the first time and was wondering how many on-going Batman comics are there?  I gather there's [Detective Comics and Batman and the differences between them](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5379/what-is-the-difference-between-action-comics-and-superman-and-detective-comics), but then [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Batman_comics) lists 11 Batman comics as of October 2011.  How do they all fit together?  Are they all just stand-alone stories that happen to share Batman as their main character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wikipedia entry on the [DC Comics New 52](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52#Batman), specifically the Batman Section, can tell you the list of what is currently being published.

The list reproduced:

- Batman
- Detective Comics
- Batwing
- Batman: The Dark Knight
- Batman and Robin
- Batgirl
- Batwoman
- Nightwing
- Catwoman
- Birds of Prey
- Red Hood and the Outlaws

**Each series has it's own *distinct story* and flavor to it.** There is no overlap in story lines so far.

Edited to add emphasis on the answer.

Comment: That doesn't really answer how the multiple Batman comics fit together, i.e. all standalone, some interlinked, etc.

Comment: The last sentence did, edited to add emphasis and clarifying text.

Comment: What about [Night of the Owls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Night_of_the_Owls)?